# drop down country selection for phone country code in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

Rails noob here posing a question.

I'm trying to get users to input their phone number. Form contains separate fields for countrycode, areacode and phonenumber at the moment.

```
<% form_tag phones_path, :method => 'get' do %>
<th><%= text_field_tag :countrycode %></th>
<th><%= text_field_tag :areacode %></th>
<th><%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %></th>
<th><%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %></th>
<% end %>
```

I want to convert the countrycode field into a dropdown selection of country names, and automatically display the actual country code upon selection. Eg user selections USA, and +1 is displayed. I am going to store both the country name and the numerical code.

I think I need to use a combination of collection_select for the dropdown and javascript to refresh the display. But I'm kinda lost as to how to proceed. Will any kind soul give some hints please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you should create a hash in your controller that looks like:

```
@countries  = { "United States" => "+1", "Switzerland" => "+41" }
```

Then create a select list for the countries and add an onchange javascript event handler for the select list:

```
<% form_tag phones_path, :method => 'get' do %>
<th>
  <%= select_tag  :country, 
                  options_for_select(@countries), 
                  :onchange => "document.getElementById('countrycode').value = this.options[selectedIndex].value;" 
  %>
</th>
<th><%= text_field_tag :countrycode %></th>
<th><%= text_field_tag :areacode %></th>
<th><%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %></th>
<th><%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %></th>
<% end %>
```

**Note:** I've used standard Javascript for the onchange event, if you use jQuery or prototypeJS this could be written much shorter and cleaner :)

Comment: remark: if you have a model for the countries with their country code then you can use [options_from_collection_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select) instead of the hash ;)

Comment: good comment. I personally would avoid manually building up the select options when possible

Comment: That's a great start for me, and works well. I would like to make the countrycode text_field_tag to a non-editable display instead of a form. If I use :disable, it doesnt get sent. Should I do some other way?

Comment: yes i think i will fix up a model for it. makes it more versatile to work with later on, especially with ~100 countries...

Comment: @julien: Have a look at the [readonly attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp)

Comment: missing '=' sign i believe. "<% form_tag" to "<%= form_tag"

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:subject_heading_source_id, SubjectHeadingSource.all, :id, :name, :prompt => "Please select...") %>
```

This is dependent upon having the contents of the select represented in a table somewhere and using the "form_for" approach to building your form, so it may not be entirely applicable.

EDIT: accidental-submit, sorry.

I use jQuery to find the element and update it:

```
$("#phones_path_country_code").attr("selected", value_of_selection)
```

you put this part into :onchange => "..." in the html options for the erb bit.

My jQuery is likely off but you can get a better idea at the api site. [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com)